# How to find the reduced echelon form of a homogenous linear system given only the solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm having a hard time understanding this question:

Determine the reduced echelon form of the homogeneous linear system of three equations in variables $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4}, x_{5}$ such that $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{4}$ are
leading variables; $x_{3}, x_{5}$ are free variables and which has solutions

$$\begin{pmatrix}2 \\-1\\1\\0\\0 \end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\begin{pmatrix}-3 \\2\\0\\-4\\1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have
\begin{cases}
x_1=2x_3-3x_5\\
x_2=-x_3+2x_5\\
x_4=-4x_5
\end{cases}
which means
\begin{cases}
x_1-2x_3+3x_5=0\\
x_2+x_3-2x_5=0\\
x_4+4x_5=0
\end{cases}
This system's matrix is what you're looking for.

If you can't see why, here's a different strategy: the matrix must be of the form
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & a & 0 & b \\
0 & 1 & c & 0 & d \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & e
\end{bmatrix}
and the two given vectors should be in its null space.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks!!